# session_start() causing Fatal Error Call to a member function AddItem() on a non-object?

Tags: php

I'm trying to add items to a shopping cart.

I get the following error `Fatal Error Call to a member function AddItem() on a non-object`

here is my shoppingCart class

```
class shoppingCart
{
    protected $items = array();

    public function AddItem($product_id)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($product_id, $this->items))
                $this->items[$product_id] = $this->items[$product_id] + 1;

          else 
              $this->items[$product_id] = 1;
    }

    public function GetItems()
    {
        return array_keys($this->items);
    }

    public function GetItemQuantity($product_id)
    {
        return $this->items[$product_id];
    }

}
```

and the specific line that's causing the error is `$shopping_cart->AddItem($product_id);`

here is the full segment:

```
$product_id = $_REQUEST['id'];
           if (product_exists($product_id))
            {
                 $shopping_cart->AddItem($product_id);
                 echo "Item Added";
            }
```

Interestingly, I started getting this error as soon as I added session_start() in my functions file, which is as follows:

```
session_start();

// Getting the Catalogue
function get_xml_catalog()
{
return new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents(STORE_XML_FILE));
}



// Creating the product list on courses.php
function generate_items()
{
    foreach (get_xml_catalog() as $product)
                {
                   echo '<div class="span4">
                        <div class="service-main">
                        <div class="service-icon"> <i class="icon-beaker"></i> </div>
                        <div class="service-info">
                        <h3>',$product->title,'</h3>
                        <p>',$product->description,'</p>
                        <a href="addToCart.php?id=',$product->id,'">Add To Cart</a>
                          </div>
                         </div>
                         </div>

                        ';
                }
}

//Passing Data into the shopping cart session.
function get_shopping_cart()
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
        return new ShoppingCart();

    else 
        return unserialize($_SESSION['cart']);
}
function set_shopping_cart($cart)
{
    $_SESSION['cart'] = serialize($cart);
}

//Checking to make sure the product ID is valid (exists) in our catalogue.
function product_exists($product_id)
{

    foreach (get_xml_catalog() as $product)
    {
        if ($product->id==$product_id)
            return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

I read online that adding serialize/unserialize would fix this error, but that didn't change anything. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - when I remove `session_start()` the functions work and I can var_dump $shopping_cart with the item being passed through it. When I have session_start(), none of the functions inside shoppingCart work. Even when I change `AddItem()`to a function that doesnt exist, I still get the same error. I'm sure it's some how related to sessions.

Comment: What does a `var_dump($shopping_cart)` right before the error-causing line output?

Comment: it comes up as null. Not sure why, since $shopping_cart should have new shoppingCart() passed to it, or just return $_SESSION['cart']

Comment: I guess you have to call `$shopping_cart = get_shopping_cart();` beforehand.

Comment: I call that at the beginning. right after I use require_once functions.php. But still no luck!

Comment: What's the value of `$_SESSION['cart']`?

Comment: `N;` if I vardump $shopping_cart it's null. Something is wrong with the session for sure... but I can't figure out what

Answer (score 3):

This should do it if you haven't done already:

```
$shopping_cart = new shoppingCart();

$product_id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    if (product_exists($product_id)) {
    $shopping_cart->AddItem($product_id);
    echo "Item Added";
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. I can't believe I missed that LOL! I feel so silly. Thank you.. I was looking for such elaborate solutions for some reason.

Comment: I am glad my answer solved your problem. This is my first experience with stackoverflow :)

Comment: The only thing I'm curious about is that if $_SESSION['cart'] was not set, it would've returned new shoppingCart() as per the functions file

Comment: Oh figured it out! I wrote `if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
        return new ShoppingCart();` instead of `shoppingCart`. I misstyped the lowercase `s` as an uppercase. But thanks to your solution it made me realize the mistake!

Comment: actually, for some reason I'm still getting the error even though i fixed shoppingCart(). If I add new shoppingCart() above the $product_id request, then everytime a product is sent to the cart I'm creating a new cart. Any other ideas?

Comment: Before creating a new object check if object exist. if ( !$shopping_cart). This way you will not override your existing object.

Comment: that gives me an undefined variable, and just keeps recreating the cart. I've tried if($shopping_cart) as well

Comment: I guess, I need it to run with the sessions because if it doesn't get registered to a session it'll just keep creating a new cart. I think the problem is with this section `function get_shopping_cart()
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
        return new ShoppingCart();

    else 
        return unserialize($_SESSION['cart']);
}`

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in this code.

```
function get_shopping_cart()
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
        return new ShoppingCart();

    else 
        return unserialize($_SESSION['cart']);
}
```

If session is not set, you are returning object and that object is used to call further methods of shoppingCart class but in case your session is set, you are returning unserialized data and using that as class object.

Comment: I've tried to remove the serialize, but it hasn't solved it. It seems for some reason my get_shopping_cart() is not working as intended. Any ideas on how to fix the code?